# How do i fix the slow scroll in browsers and high XOrg cpu usage

Tags: xorg, nvidia, firefox, cpu-load, mouse-scroll

I am facing an issue while scrolling in browsers(firefox, chrome, and opera) , scroll is jagged and slow. Also when scrolling the cpu usage spikes.

I am currently running ubuntu natty(beta 1), switched from ubuntu 10.10 where the problem was worse. I am using the nvidia beta driver, which ubuntu installed automatically. My graphic card is nvidia Quadro NVS 150M.

I tried running ubuntu without the effects on , but when using multiple applications at the same time xorg usage spikes again.

Additional info: 2GB of RAM and an intel core 2 duo processor.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I had this problem in my old PC, but it was much older than yours and also using opera instead of firefox made things much better.

Comment: Which application is causing the cpu spike in the first instance: browser or xorg?

Comment: Hi! was this problem solved?

Answer (score 2):

I  would say that this is normal usage. It takes plenty of effort for the cpu to redraw the screen. That being said, the smooth-scrolling option and extensions in Firefox make the scrolling somewhat erratic, compared to Chromium and Opera. Simply scrolling up and down (with a smooth-scrolling extension) causes cpu usage to spike for Firefox but not for Xorg. For me with Chromium however, Xorg spikes more. I have a an old ARM11 smartphone without a graphics chip and I get better scrolling on that then on my desktop. A smartphone with a graphics chip can get 60fps while scrolling a webpage. Chromium 14 is supposed to have proper smooth scrolling baked in, utilizing the graphics chip. Hardware acceleration in Firefox is supposed to arrive in v6 but for me, running b2 with an nvidia card, the scrolling has not improved. Hardware acceleration in Opera was supposed to arrive with the latest version (11.50) but it didn't make it.